# String.Format of a ByteArray converts 0x00 to 0, how can I retain 00

Tags: c#, string-formatting

I am trying to print each `byte` in an array (Byte Array) using a for loop. However since I am using the `String.Format`, it converts the 0x00 in the `byte` array to a 0. How can I print it as 00.

```
Trace.Write("\n--->");
for (int K = 1; K <= j; K++)
Debug.Write(string.Format("{0:X}", FrameByteArray[K]));
```

I know it should be simple, but I have a hard time figuring it out.

Please advice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `{0:X2}` instead - this will ensure the number will always have at least two characters.

Comment: might be worth to add a reference to the documentation? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx#mt110